# Need help creating a google web app form that can incorporate Stripe "Place a hold on a card" Api for card pre-authorisation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, stripe-payments

Trying to create a simple web form that receives fields like

1. Name
2. Location
3. Etc
   The form data is to be sent to Google Sheet

Once the user clicks submit, it should then call the Stripe "Place a hold on a card" function
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later

Not sure how to go about this..

The web form is to be on Google WebApp (Appscript)

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't using a clear "server" here but rather hooking into a Google Sheet, my recommendation would be to use PaymentLinks from Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links.

The alternative is to create a CheckoutSession on your "server" (not sure how you'd do it from a Google Sheet, especially not if it is a public Google sheet) but you'd need to create and redirect to a CheckoutSession: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web.